# Why is git clone not copying source files to my local directory?

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone

I'm running into issues using git clone.
When I run the command to clone a repository, the git command looks like it completes successfully.

```
git clone ssh://username@192.168.2.4:29418/sourceName
```

I get the following results:

```
ssh://username@192.168.2.4:29418/sourceName
Cloning into 'sourceName'...
Warning: Permanently added '[192.168.2.4]:29418' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
remote: Counting objects: 14091, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (14091/14091)
remote: Total 14091 (delta 10639), reused 13901 (delta 10639)
Receiving objects: 100% (14091/14091), 84.60 MiB | 204.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (10639/10639), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

So, it looks like it's cloning successfully.
But when I look at the target folder, I see only the .git folder gets created and populated.

No source files get copied locally as part of the clone.

I don't see any error messages.
What could be going wrong? 
How do I "debug" this?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: Does the repo contain no files?  What does `git log` show?

Comment: You're seeing whatever content's in the cloned repo's `HEAD` commit. do `git branch` and check out something that's got content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. First, git said it received 84.6 MiB of objects, so sanity check:
   `du -hs .git/objects`
2. If it's empty, perhaps you are not actually in the target folder.
3. If it's not empty, `git log --all`. This just asks git log to follow
   all refs from `refs/`.

   You might discover that the source files were there before, but were removed in a subsequent commit. If so, just `git checkout` to an older commit.

   Also possible that there's simply no files in the `master` branch (`git log --all` will show other branches). See `git branch` for list and `git checkout` another branch.
4. If that's empty, manually inspect `.git/refs/heads`,
   `.git/refs/remotes`, and finally `.git/objects`. GitHowTo has a good [overview of .git directory structure](https://githowto.com/git_internals_git_directory).